# Is there a Rogue Amoeba SoundSource (MacOS app) equivalent for Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, windows-10, audio-recording, music-production

It is a pain to open up sound settings, and then click Advanced Sound settings to change Audio input/output and redirection of sound.

I was under the impression from watching a video about improving sound quality in OBS or Voicemeeter (I can't seem to find the video again) that there is an application that sits on the taskbar or system tray that provides similar functionality to [Soundsource][1] from Rogue Amoeba on the Mac, which makes it easy to change Audio I/O settings and even redirect sound per application (with some basic effects and EQ adjustments) on the fly. I would much appreciate it if someone could clue me in. I checked other sites for ideas, but was unable to find comparable Windows apps.

Answer (score 1):

Equalizer APO https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/ with Peace https://sourceforge.net/projects/peace-equalizer-apo-extension/ offers some of SoundSource offers, but it a far cry. Eq APO supports VST plugins, but CanOpener Studio, for example, doesn't work.

Peace is nice as it gives you tray access to your presets. There are a few crossfeed settings, and a number of others ones. The whole thing is quite nerdy, but fun to play with.

There's supposed to be much more software for windows than mac, but I'm not finding true in every category.